# Is there a way to compare every array value with eachother effectively?

Tags: c#, algorithm, methods

So Ive been trying to compare given double values in an array with eachother to return the smallest one, but the way I do it does not seem to work consistently and very efficient. Im feeling lost.

```
public static double FindSmallestNum(double[] arr) 
    {
            double max = 0;
      for (int x=0;x<arr.Length-1;x++){
                if ( arr[x]>= arr[x+1]){
                    if (max >= arr[x+1]){
                       max = arr[x+1];
                    }
                }
                else if (max >=arr[x]){
                        max = arr[x];
                }
                else {
                            max = arr[x];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
```

Comment: You can use LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Finding the smallest number is easy - just scan from start to end, keeping the smallest value you've found until then in a local variable. There's no need to compare elements at all. The loop should contain nothing more than `if (min>arr[x]){min=arr[x];}`. In the end, `min` will contain the minimum value. That's `O(N)`

Comment: If you want faster performance and have a *lot* of data, you can use Parallel LINQ to use a paralleled `Min` implementation, or [System.Numerics.Vectors.Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector4.min?view=netcore-3.1) to compare up to 4 values at the same time using SIMD operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please post your comments as an answer, as that's exactly what they are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use Linq:

```
var min = arr.OrderBy(v => v).FirstOrDefault();
```

min will be the smallest number in your array.

Comment: this is not optimized

Comment: This is a *very* bad idea and shouldn't be the accepted solution  - it's not just that LINQ has a `Min()` method, this is *far more expensive* than the original code - it tries to sort the array then pick the first item, resulting in a *LOT* of CPU and RAM waste. Even for sorting `Array.Sort` would be faster

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use `System.Linq` (which it appears that you are, given the accepted answer), then you may as well just go straight to the [`Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netcore-3.1) method:

```
public static double FindSmallestNum(double[] arr)
{
    return arr.Min();
}
```

Although, given that it's a simple one-line method call, it's not clear that a helper method is really all that helpful in this case.

---

**Problems with your code**

In your sample code, it appears that the problem is that you set `max = 0;` (why do you call it `max` instead of `min`?) and then start doing comparisons to see if `max` is larger than items in the array. This can be problematic, since all positive numbers will be larger than `max`, so they will never be considered.

To fix this, first let's rename that variable to `min`, so we remember what we're doing, and then set it to the first value in the array. This way we know we're dealing with a number in our array, and all comparisons will be valid.

Next, we don't need to compare each item with the next item - that comparison is not relevant to finding the smallest of all the items. We only need to compare each item to the current value of `min` (and do the necessary reassignment if we find a lower number).

This would reduce the code to something like:

```
public static double FindSmallestNum(double[] input)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (input.Length == 0) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("array contains no elements");

    // Start with the first number
    double smallest = input[0];

    // Now compare the rest of the items with 'smallest'
    for (int index = 1; index < input.Length; index++)
    {
        if (input[index] < smallest) smallest = input[index];
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can further be optimized. you can see the below logic. Complexity of this code is O(N)

```
static void GetSmallest(int[] arr)
{
    int first, arr_size = arr.Length;

    first = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < first)
        {
            first = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the below code also.

```
int[] arr = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int min = arr.Min();
```